# Why is vim offering me spelling suggestions instead of using the completefunc?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I am trying to set up vim for writing email.  I have a plugin to provide autocompletion of email addresses ([notmuch abook](https://github.com/guyzmo/notmuch-abook) ). If I do `:set completefunc` it tells me it is `CompleteAddressBook` as expected.

However, when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> I get what appear to be spelling suggestions from a word dictionary.  I do have `spell` set, but I'm confused as to how to get past spell to get `completefunc` used.

You can see [my vimrc](https://github.com/foobacca/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc.vundle) in case there is something weird in there.

Ideas for debugging steps welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that rather than using <kbd>Tab</kbd> I had to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>

See the [compl-function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#compl-function) docs for more.